# Plotly Multi Column Horizontal Legend

Tags: r, r-markdown, plotly

I am trying to create horizontal bar chart in in R using the plotly package.  Due to the length of the legend items I would like for them to show horizontally at the top or bottom of the visual in 2 columns. Is it possible to dictate the number of columns for the legend?

I've been able to place the legend below the x axis successfully using `Layout(legend = list(orientation='h'))` however regardless of where I put the legend (using the x and y arguments) it is always just one long list.  I've seen a github project for creating a multi column legend in js but not r.

Thanks,

Comment: R Plotly is just passing a JSON to JS Plotly, so if you cannot do in JS, you cannot do it in R either.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in a normal way. I think it has its own logic that determines how many place there it is and how many columns it will display then.

So I guess if you make your plot width smaller you could reach the goal that it will just display 2 column.

Also you can try to play around with the margin attribute (https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-margin) by setting `r` and `l` to 10 e.g.

An other idea could be to make the font-size in legend (https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-legend-font-size) bigger, so that it just uses two columns. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I read the same github page and I thought that it is not possible, but seems to be! I only checked in Python, but I hope this will help in your endeavors in R as well as everyone in Python looking for information. Sadly, there is not a lot of information on Plotly here compared to other packages.

#### This solved my problem

Setting `orientation='h'` is not enough. You also have to put the legend items in different `legendgroup`s, if you want them in different columns. Here is an example with legend labels:

```
fig = go.Figure([
go.Scatter(x=best_neurons_df['Test Size'],
    y=best_neurons_df['Training Accuracy Max'],
# You can write anything as the group name, as long as it's different.
    legendgroup="group2", 
    name='Training',
    mode='markers',
go.Scatter(x=best_neurons_df['Test Size'],
    y=best_neurons_df['Validation Accuracy Max'],
# You can write anything as the group name, as long as it's different.
    legendgroup="group1",
layout=dict(title='Best Model Dependency on Validation Split',
    xaxis=dict(title='Validation Set proportion'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Accuracy'),
    margin=dict(b=100, t=100, l=0, r=0),
    legend=dict(x=1, y=1.01,xanchor='right', yanchor='bottom',
        title='', 
        orientation='h', # Remember this as well.
        bordercolor='black',
        borderwidth=1
))
```

[image: Example image]
[Example image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hPyMliMpqx4hR8fjPMzs5J08v2Ui_ukk/view?usp=sharing)